# How to get data from Django Many-Many relationship?

Tags: django, django-templates

How to get all product for every order on Templates. Please help me

Model.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer_id= models.ForeignKey(Customers )
    delivery_add_id= models.ForeignKey(DeliveryAddresses)




class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='orderId')
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('Products', related_name='productId')



class Products(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.ForeignKey('Categories')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

---

Templates

```
   <tr>
        <th>Product ordered</th>
        <td>
             <ul>
                {% for prod in order.orderId.productId.product_set.all%}
                <li>{{pro}}</li>
                {% endfor %}

            </ul> 

            {{order.orderId.productId.product_set.all}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ3zG.png

---

Views.py

```
class productList(ListView):
    model= Products
    context_object_name = 'product_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Products.objects.all()

class productDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'product'
    model = Products
    queryset = Products.objects.all()


class orderList(ListView):
    model = Order
    context_object_name= 'order_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.all()


class orderDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name ='order'
    model = Order
    queryset= Order.objects.all()
```

---

This is the general relationship I have set up.I'm trying to do is, in a templates, i want to show all product for every order. Order-product : many to many relationship. Please help me

Comment: Stop calling your foreign keys names ending in "_id". They're not IDs, they're actual objets. And *definitely* stop calling your related names the name of the FK model ending in "Id". That's doubly wrong; the related name points *back* to the source model, and is the *collection* of all the related model instances. Finally, use InitialCaps not camelCase for your view names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
{% for orderItem in order.orderId.all %}
   {% for pro in orderItem.productId.all %}
                <li>{{pro}}</li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```